# What is the best practive to name functions/variables for Chrome Extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I developed a Chrome extension and it injects code into a website that is loaded on the active tab. My code is fairly complex and long with bunch of global variables and functions. As this code is inserted into another website, I am curios if this would create conflicts with page's global variables and functions.

What is the best practice to handle this issue?

Thanks for your guidance and I'd happy to elaborate further if the above is not clear enough.

Doug

Comment: A good practice is to not expose global variables at all. You can do this easily by wrapping your code with an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), and making sure all your variables are declared _(i.e. you didn't forget any `var`, `const` or `let` keyword)_

Comment: There is not best practice to name function or variable. We can surely improve it a little bit by giving some sensible and readable names.

Comment: Many thanks for the answers. How should I handle the added HTML element ids? I am trying to make them as random as possible but any other advice?

Comment: You can also use your app/chrome extension’s name to name the variables, like <extension-name>_var1.

Comment: Many thanks folks, appreciate the help

Comment: The best practice is to never add globals into the scope of a foreign page. Why do you do it? It's really bad.